# Building lightweight Java native programs

Tags: java, dll, netbeans, jvm

So I just started developing native programs in Java with Netbeans, creating setup scripts for them with Inno Script. But then I noticed even basic programs tend to be quite resource heavy, this because every program has its own copy of Java Virtual Machine runtimes needed for it to execute. I figured a good solution would be to have the JVM runtimes installed to a unified folder (since aren't they just the same files copied into every single program?) from which each individual program can then run the shared files.

The problem is, I don't really know how to go about this. Where exactly do I install the runtimes to and how do I set up this path so that any native Java programs run on the computer will automatically detect and use them? Would adding the shared directory to the %PATH% environment be enough or not?

Please help. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I haven't really tried anything yet since I felt maybe I should get some advice first.

::: UPDATE :::
So, I think I've figured out a possible solution to my problem, though I'm yet to try it because I can't access my IDE and other tools until later tomorrow for reasons. But what I was thinking is that perhaps I could install the shared Java Virtual Machine runtimes to a directory then add the directory to the %PATH% environment variable so its runtimes can be executed just as system DLLs are. I'll post an update on the results of the theory as soon as I can.

Comment: You [don't need](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9) 3rd party tools. Java can install an embedded vm with resources where you want them

Comment: If you are really concerned with Java being heavyweight, you should probably be using a non-GC'd language that compiles to native code executables; i.e. C or C++.

Comment: How do you _know_ this is true? => _"even basic programs tend to be quite resource heavy, this because every program has its own copy of Java Virtual Machine runtimes needed for it to execute"_. And specifically, what do you mean by _"quite resource heavy"_? To be clear, I'm not agreeing or disagreeing with your claim, but when you make that claim the core of your question you really need to provide some evidence. You are seeking a solution without demonstrating that there is a problem to be solved.

Comment: @skomisa, well, I wrote a simple, blank GUI program and it still ended up taking about 200+ MBs of space. I checked and most of that was just the JVM runtimes, which is why I want them moved to a shared folder. That way, I won't be taking up 200+ MBs of space with every one of my apps because the apps will be using the same runtimes instead of each having their own copy of them.

Comment: @JuancarlosKaiShiro OK. In that case you should add that information to your question. As implied by Basil's answer, you haven't clearly specified the specific improvement(s) you are looking for. Therefore any answers are necessarily just speculation. And without metrics, how can you know if any changes you make are actually beneficial?

Comment: You should mention that you’re using JavaFX, as the JavaFX runtime is even bigger than the Java runtime. You can strip off unneeded things from a modular Java environment, but that doesn’t help when the actual space consumption doesn’t originate from the Java runtime. Using a shared runtime is a neat idea; it basically means you re-invented non-native aka *ordinary* Java programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem now.

I tried out my original theory, but it didn't work because turns out native Java programs (or at least those compiled using Java FX under Netbeans) are hard-wired to search for JVM runtimes in a specific folder and this folder is defined in a simple, text-based configuration file. And so, instead of adding the custom  folder in which I install the JVM runtimes to the %PATH% environment variable, I just had to change the runtime directory in the configuration file.

[That's the native Java program compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evX29.png)

[That's the directory of the configuration file in the program's files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1bHT.png)

[That's the modified configuration file. I just had to change the value of app.runtime to the custom location of my shared JVM runtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmgqO.png)

[The native Java program, now customised so that the runtime folder installs to my shared directory instead; this defined in the configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEQYU.png)

[My shared runtime folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuxDI.png)

[Inside the JVM binaries of the runtime directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwjrq.png)

[The native Java program, now without its own runtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbG9G.png)

With these customisations, I can now run two seperate Java native programs on a computer without Java without having them each own their own runtimes, instead sharing the runtimes in the shared runtimes folder (defined in their respective configuration files). I've also configured the setups for the native programs so that should the shared runtimes not be installed on the target computer, they will be when any one of the programs is installed or repaired through its setup. Also, newer, modified runtimes can easily be set to override older ones, updating the runtimes in the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use a default installer of OpenJDK for your operating system and if the installer doesn't do it just add the bin directory of the JAVA HOME directory to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your highest priority is a small size of the executable, Java is not appropriate. You should use a language designed to compile down to a simple native executable with a minimal executable. For example, Swift, Rust, and C.

If you want to continue with Java while minimizing the size of your software artifact, then:

1. [Modularize](https://www.simonandschuster.com/books/The-Java-Module-System/Nicolai-Parlog/9781617294280) your app with the Java [Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).
2. Use the [*jlink*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) tool to assemble and optimize a set of modules and their dependencies into a custom run-time image. Rather than bring in the entire collection of classes provided with a JVM, only the classes of the modules actually used by your particular app are included.
3. Use the [*jpackage*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) tool to package a Java application into a platform-specific package. Supported platform-specific package formats are… Linux: deb and rpm, macOS: pkg and dmg, Windows: msi and exe.

If speed of launch time is a priority, consider using a JVM with [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) rather than [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9).

If speed of execution is a priority, use ahead-of-time compilation of your Java application with [*GraalVM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) technology.

You said:

> I figured a good solution would be to have the JVM runtimes installed to a unified folder

You can assume a JRE or JDK has been installed on the user’s machine. Then you need not include any Java runtime with your software artifact.

Obviously this is only practical if either (a) your user base is using managed computers such as in a corporate or educational environment, or (b) your users are eager enough and savvy enough to obtain and install a [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment)/[JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) on their own.

In the early years of Java, Sun Microsystems was able to convince most of the personal computer industry to bundle a JRE with their computers. But that practice ended many years ago.